# Restricting WCF TCP endpoint to Administrators

Tags: authentication, administration, nettcpbinding, wcf

How do I restrict access of a remotely-accessible WCF endpoint to a local/domain **administrator**?

---

**Edit:** After adding `[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "AdminUser")]` to my WCF channel method implementation, trying to call the service method from my client throws a `SecurityAccessDeniedException`, which is progress.

How do I let Windows prompt the user for new user details (or a security token) so I can reinitiate the WCF connection *as* the correct user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the **PrincipalPermissionAttribute** added to the methods declared in your WCF service.

See this link: [How to: Restrict Access with the PrincipalPermissionAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200.aspx)